# How to solve "Type 'System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel' is not defined?

Tags: visual-studio, error, asp.net, updatepanel

I'm using an update panel on a form to stop the page jumping and flickering when drop down lists etc are selected, I have enclosed the table which holds this inside of an update panel and a content template.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
<ContentTemplate>
   (drop downs here)
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This runs fine and does exactly what I need but at the bottom of visual studio an error message reads "Type 'System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel' is not defined" and I can't seem to get arid of it! It doesn't stop my solution from deploying or running and it doesn't affect its functionality, the update panel works, I just don't like having the error.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this one hope you get some hint from this

http://forums.asp.net/t/1600846.aspx